# How to backup Samsung 6 edge data with broken USB port

Tags: samsung, usb

My USB port on my mobile is dodgy, intermittent charging slowly reducing to no charging! I took it in to shop and they're happy to send it away to be fixed, however I need to back it up, and i've downloaded Kies, but of course the cable from the phone's USB port isn't working properly so I can't seem to get the phone connected to back up my connects and calendar. Any suggestions?
I've got a google account and synced the contacts (although I couldn't see my calendar), but how do I know this has been synced and how do I recover it?
Is there a way to back up through bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [smart switch app](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00047056/) to send to a different Samsung phone.

I've noticed that calendar tasks on Samsung doesn't sync with Google or with anything else, only smart switch or kies worked me.